# Codename One Java Scanner - Mobile App Build Error

Tags: java, android, codenameone, barcode-scanner

I am building a Codename One Mobile Java app that requires to scan bar codes. I get build error on the build server. It used to work but of late in the last month I can't build a scanner app. Has anyone encountered this challenge? How can I resolve it? Below are the steps I took. Thanks!

I created a sample cn1 hello world barebones app with the native theme.

I imported these after adding the cn1-codescan and QRScanner libs using the Codename One Settings Wizard.
ext.codescan.CodeScanner and codename1.ext.codescan.ScanResult and littlemonkey.qrscanner.QRScanner

I created button to scan a bar code.

```
Button btn_scanBarcode = new Button("Barcode");
btn_scanBarcode.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
    {
        if (CodeScanner.getInstance() != null) 
        {
            QRScanner.scanBarCode(new ScanResult() 
            {
                public void scanCompleted(String contents, String formatName, byte[] rawBytes) 
                {
                    Dialog.show("Completed", contents, "OK", null);
                }

                public void scanCanceled() 
                {
                    Dialog.show("Cancelled", "Scan Cancelled", "OK", null);
                }

                public void scanError(int errorCode, String message) 
                {
                    Dialog.show("Error", message, "OK", null);
                }
            });
        } 
        else 
        {
            Dialog.show("Not Supported","Bar Code Scanning is not available on this device","OK",null);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Add the error message

Comment: The error experienced is on the cloud build server and is as follows:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute activity#com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity@label value=(@string/app_name) from AndroidManifest.xml:25:114-146
   is also present at [:ZBarScannerLibrary:] AndroidManifest.xml:18:13-36 value=(Scanner).
   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:3-149 to override.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the old cn1libs and install the latest version from the extension manager UI within `Codename One Settings`.

I suggest deleting the `ios.*` and `android.*` build hints too so refresh client libs will update them to the latest version.

Comment: Did that but build still fails on CN1 dashboard - error shown next to Jens comment above also shown below:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute activity#com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity@label value=(@string/app_name) from AndroidManifest.xml:25:114-146
   is also present at [:ZBarScannerLibrary:] AndroidManifest.xml:18:13-36 value=(Scanner).
   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:3-149 to override.

Comment: Did you install the barcode scanning library from us as well? You need both the QR scanner and our scanner for everything to work now. If this still doesn't work I'll need the full error log you can just edit your question and paste it there.

Comment: Yes, via Codename One Settings Extensions manager, I first added your cn1-codescan library then the QRScanner library from little monkey.

You can find the dashboard output error from the build server here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByFcLKTw1_LycHMyalBWZ0dQeDQ

Comment: Interestingly, I can get scanning to work on an old app. Perhaps it is the configurations on my machine that could have changed somehow thus preventing me from creating new projects with scanning capability. Am  powering a Windows 10 64 with Netbeans IDE 8.1 and JDK 8 update 91.

Comment: Did you remove the android.* and ios.* build hints before doing a refresh libs? What are your android.* build hints?

Comment: Yes I removed anything from build hints that belonged to ios or android. After refreshing libs some came back. Then I sent another build but it failed again. The error text file is in the link above. The build hints screenshots are also included. Please have a look! Meanwhile I think I found the cause of the fail.

I had a look at the build hints for the old app that works and I noticed that it doesn't have the android.xapplication build hint i.e. <activity android:name="com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:label="@string/app_name" />

Comment: It looks like you left an old cn1lib or something else lying around somewhere in your project.

Comment: I've tried deleting all the libs even manually from the source folder and repeated the steps you have shared but to no avail. The link to the error I am getting is: https://s3.amazonaws.com/codenameone-build-response/10f0d649-fae4-4e42-a638-58464454a2ba-1473935236236-error.txt

Comment: I got the scanner working by removing the QRScanner lib and retaining the external cn1-codescan library. I will keep trying to see if I can get the internal scanner working. The issue must be with the QRScanner library from littlemonkey. I'll appreciate any help if anyone has got scanner working using the littlemonkey lib.

Comment: Yes, it's an issue there. You can file an issue with us and we'll try to look at it when we get the time.